# Optimization in Typed Racket... Is this going too far?

Tags: optimization, integer, racket, typed-racket

A question about typed/racket. I'm currently working my way through the [Euler Project problems](https://projecteuler.net/archives) to better learn racket. Some of [my solutions](https://github.com/nico7et8/euler_racket) are really slow, especially when dealing with primes and factors. So for some problems, I've tried to make a typed/racket version and I find no improvement in speed, quite the opposite. (I try to minimize the impact of overhead by using really big numbers, calculations are around 10 seconds.)

I know from the Racket docs that the best optimizations happen [when using Floats/Flonums](http://docs.racket-lang.org/ts-guide/optimization.html). So... yeah, I've tried to make float versions of problems dealing with integers. As in [this problem](https://projecteuler.net/problem=21) with a [racket version](https://github.com/nico7et8/euler_racket/blob/master/21.rkt) using integers, and a [typed/racket one](https://github.com/nico7et8/euler_racket/blob/master/21-typed.rkt) artificially turning integers to floats. I have to use tricks: checking equality between two numbers actually means checking that they are "close enough", like in this function which checks if x can be divided by y :

```
(: divide? (-> Flonum Flonum Boolean))
(define (divide? x y)
  (let ([r (/ x y)])
    (< (- r (floor r)) 1e-6)))
```

It works (well... the solution is correct) and I have a 30%-40% speed improvement.

How acceptable is this? Do people actually do that in real life? If not, what is the best way to optimize typed/racket solutions when using integers? Or should typed/racket be abandoned altogether when dealing with integers and reserved for problems with float calculations?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In most cases the solution is to use better algorithms rather than converting to Typed Racket.

Since most problems at Project Euler concern integers, here is a few tips and tricks:

1. The division operator `/` needs to compute the greatest common division between the denominator and the numerator in order to cancel out common factors. This makes `/` a bad choice if you only want to know whether one number divides another. Use `(= (remainder n m) 0)` to check whether `m` divides `n`. Also: use `quotient` rander than `/` when you know the division has a zero remainder.
2. Use memoization to avoid recomputation. I.e. use a vector to store already computed results. Example: https://github.com/racket/math/blob/master/math-lib/math/private/number-theory/eulerian-number.rkt
3. First implement a naive algorithm. Then consider how to reduce the number of cases. A rule of thumb: brute force works best if you can reduce the number of cases to 1-10 million.
4. To reduce the number of cases look for parametrizations of the search space. Example: If you need to find a Pythagorean triple: loop over numbers m and n and then compute `a = m^2 - n^2`, `b = 2mn`, and, `c = m^2 + n^2`. This will be faster than looping over a, b, and, c skipping those triples where a^2 + b^2 = c^2 is not true.
5. Look for tips and tricks in the source of `math/number-theory`.

Comment: Note: For square roots - look into using `integer-sqrt` rather than `sqrt`.

Answer (score 2):

Not aspiring to be an real answer since I can't provide any general tips soegaard hasn't posted already, but since I recently have done "Amicable numbers
Problem 21", I thought may as well leave you my solution here (Sadly not many Lisp solutions get posted on Euler...).

```
(define (divSum n)
  (define (aux i sum)
    (if (> (sqr i) n)
        (if (= (sqr (sub1 i)) n)  ; final check if n is a perfect square
            (- sum (sub1 i))
            sum)
        (aux (add1 i) (if (= (modulo n i) 0)
                          (+ sum i (/ n i))
                          sum))))
  (aux 2 1))


(define (amicableSum n)
  (define (aux a sum)
    (if (>= a n)
        sum
        (let ([b (divSum a)])
          (aux (add1 a)
               (if (and (> b a) (= (divSum b) a))
                   (+ sum a b)
                   sum)))))
  (aux 2 0))

> (time (amicableSum 10000))
cpu time: 47 real time: 46 gc time: 0
```

When dealing with divisors one can often stop at the square-root of n like here with `divSum`. And when you find an amicable pair you may as well add both to the sum at once, what saves you an unnecessary computation of `(divSum b)` in my code.